# I Need Assistance with executing an SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I've tried with this for over 48 hours and no luck. I then create a simple package, one FTP task to download text files. I deployed the package using the option "SQL Server Deployment". I see the package in SSIS but when I try to run from command line with the command

```
dtexec /ser svrprod05 /sq Package
```

I get the error

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 9.00.3042.00 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.

Started:  10:56:39 PM
Could not load package "Package" because of error 0xC0014062.
Description: The LoadFromSQLServer method has encountered OLE DB error code 0x80
004005 (Login timeout expired).  The SQL statement that was issued has failed.
Source:
Started:  10:56:39 PM
Finished: 10:56:55 PM
Elapsed:  15.625 seconds
```

I tried passing a username and password of the following

```
1. Local Administrator
2. Domain Administrator
3. Ent Administrator
4. SQL Server SA
```

My original objective is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290153/cant-get-my-ssis-package-to-run). I don't know what else to try.

Comment: What is up with the down votes?

Comment: yea...some smart genius thinks lesser of this...wtf

Comment: I didn't vote it down, I did vote to close since I think it should be moved to Server Fault. Good luck with the problem though

Comment: isn't SSIS part of programming?

Comment: If my question can be answered on server fault, can someone please move it?

Comment: There is often a large grey area that exists between system administration tasks and programming tasks. I would say that this question seems to lie on the side of SA, and you will be more likely to catch the attention of someone on that side who is more able to answer it.

Comment: can I re-post the question on server fault without someone flagging this as a cross-post?

Comment: Probably. In order to move it to Server Fault, it requires 5 ordinary votes, or the vote from a moderator. Probably the fellow that asked the question should be able to move it themselves though?

Answer (score 1):

In my view SSIS is programming - every time something needs to be done in SSIS in our company a programmer is called to do it.
Here are a few things to try.

Try 1:
Add 
127.0.0.1 crl.microsoft.com
to the hosts file on the server.

Try 2:
providing the db_dtsoperator role to the executing user

Try 3:
Make sure you are not using the 32 bit version of DTExec on a 62 bit OS.

Comment: shoot, i want my 2 bits back!

Comment: What ProtectionLevel should I use?

Comment: I believe I narrowed it down to...my database is instance based, however when I use the command dtexec /ser svrprod05/instance /sq Package I get teh same error.